# Non-working letters from keyboard in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.10 and I came across this strange error. I can't write some specific letters such as i,g,h at startup. If I push the (for instance) <kbd>i</kbd> button, like a hundred times then all those letters starts showing up and everything working fine.

It's not relevant to keyboard or localization settings, because I added some more keyboard layouts, but nothing changed.

I couldn't find a working solution in my web searches then I upgraded the kernel to the 5.9 version. It looked like the problem solved so I deleted the old kernel files, I started using kernel 5.9 as default. But a few weeks later (after no update) the problem came back.

Problem looks easy and also not permanent but annoying, so I try to find a solution. So if anybody could help to correct this I'd appreciate.